# Is there a Fermi estimations toolbox?

Tags: resource-recommendations, estimation, fermi-problem

I am a theoretical physics student and am a little ashamed at my inability to estimate any measurable quantity. I would like to develop my skills at [Fermi estimations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem).

Although it is hopeless to start memorising physical constants, I would like to ask if there there is a compact list of quantities that are easy to memorise and useful in varied contexts to know?

For example, I learned today that a mole of Boltzmann constants is $k_B \, 10^{23} \cong 8.3$ in SI units and that, at room temperature, $k_B T \cong 1/40$ $eV$.

If someone knows where I can find a list of such tricks I would very much like to know about it.

Also, If you know one or two of these tricks, I will be happy to learn about them and make the list myself.

Comment: What's useful depends on the daily problems you are working with. For a while 42MHz/T was the most important number in my lab life, because I was doing NMR on protons. Then it became 1eV=1.6e-19J and $1nV/\sqrt{Hz}$ (it's really $0.9nV/\sqrt{Hz}$) for the noise voltage density of a 50Ohm resistor for particle physics detector development. Are these nearly as important to a theoretical physicist as the Planck scale quantities? Probably not.

Comment: Is [this set of notes](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~oom/handouts/purcell.pdf) (by a [Nobel laureate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Mills_Purcell) no less) the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Wait a sec... a mole of Boltzmann constants is exactly $R$, the ideal gas constant. That's how Boltzmann constant is defined. The ideal gas law $P = n R T$ is given with the implication that $n$ is the number density of _moles_ (number of moles per unit volume), but $k_B$ is defined so that $P = n k_B T$ represents the ideal gas law with the implication that $n$ is the number of _particles_ per unit volume. So $k_B$ is defined so that $N_A k_B = R$.

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): This seems like a list question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider it hopeless to memorize physical constants, it will probably help to find combinations of these constant that relate to the human scale. For instance:

- The gravitational constant $G$ might be difficult to memorize. This holds for both the units as well as the value. However, multiply this constant by the density of water, take the square root, and you end up with a characteristic frequency of about one per hour: $\sqrt{G \rho_w} \approx$ one per hour. If you memorize this fact, and provided you know the density of water in your preferred system of units, you can always work back to the value of $G$.
- The quantum of action $\hbar$ and the elementary charge $e$ lead to tiny values when evaluated in any day-to-day system of units. However, the ratio $\hbar / e^2 \approx 4 k \Omega$, a value more easy to remember.
- A similar relation holds for $\hbar $ and the electron mass $m_e$ their ratio gives a diffusion constant: $\hbar/m_e \approx$ one square centimeter per second.

You can augment the above with other ratios of fundamental constants that are easy to remember, such as $\sqrt{\hbar c/G} \approx 22 \mu g$ (the Planck mass), as well as with the values of dimensionless constants such as the fine structure constant.

Comment: I just learned another one: $\hbar c = 200 [MeV \, fm]$. With $c=3 \cdot 10^8 [m]$ it can be used to convert energy into length or time.

Comment: I have discovered (and am enjoying very much) [this](http://ukcatalogue.oup.com/product/9780199681198.do) book. It helps lot to get a feeling for different scales in science.

Comment: Also, check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_-Vg_B3nzM&t=493s